# How to gracefully kill clientless daemon from commandline?

Tags: emacsclient, emacs-daemon

## summary

What to utter from commandline to cause a running clientless Emacs daemon/server process to *gracefully* shutdown--i.e., clean up after itself, then exit--without creating additional Emacs processes?

Note that by `commandline`, I mean "a shell outside Emacs," not `M-x` from within Emacs (hence my question does not duplicate [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/5451/5444)), though commandline `emacsclient --eval` satisfies requirement.

Note regarding potential answers: if your answer requires some interaction, please make it either

1. *(preferred)* in the "same commandline." Not sure if that's the correct usage (please correct if not); what I mean is something like

   ```
   me@it: ~ $ your --code --here
   Save modified buffers? [Y/n] Y
   Active processes exist: kill them all? [Y/n] Y
   Killing daemon ...
   ```
2. *(acceptable)* in a TUI Emacs in the same shell as the commandline, like (e.g.) `emacsclient --tty`

## details

### testcase

Suppose one has a clientless `emacs` daemon/server process. I know I can kill said process from a (Linux) commandline with (e.g.) `kill -9 process#` or `pkill -9 emacs`, but that won't allow the process to *gracefully* shutdown. What I mean:

Let's start with no `emacs*` processes:

```
me@it: ~ $ date ; emacs --version
Sun Oct  8 00:57:18 MST 2017
GNU Emacs 24.4.1
...
```

FWIW, I'm running this on an up-to-date Debian (currently version=8.9) Linux, hence the somewhat downlevel Emacs. No emacs and no lockfiles (more below):

```
me@it: ~ $ date ; find ~/.emacs.d/ -name '*lock*'
Sun Oct  8 00:57:37 MST 2017
me@it: ~ $ date ; pgrep -l emacs
Sun Oct  8 00:57:43 MST 2017
```

Now, start a clientless `emacs` daemon/server:

```
me@it: ~ $ date ; emacs --daemon &
Sun Oct  8 01:00:05 MST 2017
...
```

`...` == omitted lots console spew from startup of my emacs config ([Emacs Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude) + some code in `~/.emacs.d/personal/`). Besides that, we can confirm the process still exists with

```
me@it: ~ $ date ; pgrep -l emacs
Sun Oct  8 01:00:56 MST 2017
29422 emacs
```

... and, since my config uses [desktop](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html), there is now a desktop lockfile (which there was not above):

```
me@it: ~ $ date ; find ~/.emacs.d/ -name '*lock*'
Sun Oct  8 01:01:01 MST 2017
/home/me/.emacs.d/personal/.emacs.desktop.lock
```

At this point, I want to tell the daemon/server process to

1. cleanup (e.g., delete its desktop lockfile), before ...
2. shutdown (e.g., kill its process) without creating additional Emacs processes (clients or servers)

### failures

#### (kill-emacs) and related

The [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Exiting.html) says

```
To kill Emacs without being prompted about saving, type M-x kill-emacs.
```

But when I do ...

```
me@it: ~ $ date ; emacsclient --eval '(kill-emacs)'
Sun Oct  8 01:02:41 MST 2017
me@it: ~ $ date ; pgrep -l emacs
Sun Oct  8 01:02:46 MST 2017
29422 emacs
me@it: ~ $ date ; find ~/.emacs.d/ -name '*lock*'
Sun Oct  8 01:02:53 MST 2017
/home/me/.emacs.d/personal/.emacs.desktop.lock
```

... there is no change. The good news is, [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5453/5444) suggests how to *actually* kill the daemon ...

```
me@it: ~ $ date ; emacsclient --eval '(let (kill-emacs-hook) (kill-emacs))'
Sun Oct  8 01:03:22 MST 2017
me@it: ~ $ date ; pgrep -l emacs
Sun Oct  8 01:03:26 MST 2017
```

... the bad news is, `(let (kill-emacs-hook) (kill-emacs))` is not graceful:

```
me@it: ~ $ date ; find ~/.emacs.d/ -name '*lock*'
Sun Oct  8 01:03:50 MST 2017
/home/me/.emacs.d/personal/.emacs.desktop.lock
```

... i.e., that code is no better than `pkill -9 emacs`.

#### (save-buffers-kill-emacs) and related

[izkon suggests](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/36003/5444) using

```
(defun server-shutdown ()
  "Save buffers, Quit, and Shutdown (kill) server"
  (interactive)
  (save-some-buffers)
  (kill-emacs))
```

which [Basil claims](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36000/how-to-gracefully-kill-clientless-daemon-from-commandline#comment56724_36003) is equal to `(save-buffers-kill-emacs)`. Let's test:

After I kill all my Emacs process and delete all lockfiles, I can add the above code to a file loaded from my `init.el`, and then do

```
me@it: ~ $ date ; find ~/.emacs.d/ -name '*lock*'
Sun Oct  8 14:08:24 MST 2017
me@it: ~ $ date ; pgrep -l emacs
Sun Oct  8 14:08:33 MST 2017
me@it: ~ $ date ; emacs --daemon &
Sun Oct  8 14:08:49 MST 2017
... console spew follows ...
me@it: ~ $ date ; pgrep -l emacs
Sun Oct  8 14:09:15 MST 2017
6087 emacs
me@it: ~ $ date ; find ~/.emacs.d/ -name '*lock*'
Sun Oct  8 14:09:25 MST 2017
/home/me/.emacs.d/personal/.emacs.desktop.lock
```

So I have a running daemon. I then do

```
me@it: ~ $ date ; emacsclient --eval '(server-shutdown)'
Sun Oct  8 14:10:25 MST 2017
me@it: ~ $ date ; pgrep -l emacs
Sun Oct  8 14:10:31 MST 2017
6087 emacs
me@it: ~ $ date ; find ~/.emacs.d/ -name '*lock*'
Sun Oct  8 14:10:33 MST 2017
/home/me/.emacs.d/personal/.emacs.desktop.lock
```

I.e., no change. However, my results from `(save-buffers-kill-emacs)` are somewhat worse:

```
me@it: ~ $ date ; emacsclient --eval '(save-buffers-kill-emacs)'
Sun Oct  8 14:11:38 MST 2017
^C
```

I.e., `(save-buffers-kill-emacs)` hangs (unlike `(server-shutdown)`) at commandline until killed with `C-c`. (This appears to be due to a [currently-open Emacs bug from 2013](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=13697), as noted [by npostavs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36000/how-to-gracefully-kill-clientless-daemon-from-commandline/36003#comment56778_36000).) Furthermore, like `(server-shutdown)` above, it does nothing about the daemon process:

```
me@it: ~ $ date ; pgrep -l emacs
Sun Oct  8 14:12:12 MST 2017
6087 emacs
me@it: ~ $ date ; find ~/.emacs.d/ -name '*lock*'
Sun Oct  8 14:12:37 MST 2017
/home/me/.emacs.d/personal/.emacs.desktop.lock
```

`(save-buffers-kill-emacs)` can be made not to hang (as [suggested by Basil](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36000/how-to-gracefully-kill-clientless-daemon-from-commandline/36003#comment56743_36003)), but it still does not work (i.e., gracefully kill the daemon):

```
me@it:~$ date ; pgrep -l emacs
Mon Oct  9 22:50:39 MST 2017
me@it:~$ date ; find ~/.emacs.d/ -name '*lock*'
Mon Oct  9 22:50:42 MST 2017
me@it:~$ date ; emacs --daemon &
Mon Oct  9 22:51:01 MST 2017
... console spew follows ...
me@it:~$ date ; pgrep -l emacs
Mon Oct  9 22:51:20 MST 2017
8378 emacs
me@it:~$ date ; find ~/.emacs.d/ -name '*lock*'
Mon Oct  9 22:51:26 MST 2017
/home/me/.emacs.d/personal/.emacs.desktop.lock
me@it:~$ date ; emacsclient --eval '(save-buffers-kill-emacs)' --tty
Mon Oct  9 22:51:51 MST 2017
```

Key `y` at the prompt (IIRC, text is `This Emacs session has clients; exit anyway?`) and the terminal client exits immediately. But it does not kill the server:

```
me@it:~$ date ; pgrep -l emacs
Mon Oct  9 22:51:59 MST 2017
8378 emacs
me@it:~$ date ; find ~/.emacs.d/ -name '*lock*'
Mon Oct  9 22:52:05 MST 2017
/home/me/.emacs.d/personal/.emacs.desktop.lock
```

Comment: I once had the same question, but gave up to find a general answer. Any code running from `kill-emacs-hook` might query for input and thus halt the shutdown process.

Comment: Re hanging, this is an open problem in Emacs, cf [Bug#13697](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=13697).

Comment: @npostavs: thanks, now noted in section=`(save-buffers-kill-emacs) and related`

Answer (score -2):

The first function in my `~/.emacs.d/init.el` is one I got from [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon):

`(defun server-shutdown ()
  "Save buffers, Quit, and Shutdown (kill) server"
  (interactive)
  (save-some-buffers)
  (kill-emacs))`

After that, I can `emacsclient -t -e '(server-shutdown)'`

Comment: I believe you can replace your `(server-shutdown)` with the built-in `(save-buffers-kill-emacs)`.

Comment: @izkon: see failure described at section=`(save-buffers-kill-emacs) and related`

Comment: @Basil: see failure described at section=`(save-buffers-kill-emacs) and related`

Comment: @TomRoche Have you tried combining `--tty` and `--eval '(save-buffers-kill-emacs)'`?

Comment: @Basil: thanks for the tip--not a fix, but one more datapoint. See updated end of section=`(save-buffers-kill-emacs) and related`